# Will not play DVD with VLC missing drivers

Tags: drivers, vlc, dvd

Last year I put Ubuntu 13.10 in this laptop with VLC to play DVDs had problem with drivers called Samsung and they told me to install drivers,but now I put Ubuntu 14.04 in and no longer have drivers. I think i entered apt-get css to get them does any 1 have any Idea.last year laptop was under warranty now it isn’t so if I call them they will charge me for the answer

Comment: Please consider edit your question and use proper gramar, I can barely understand what you try to say.

Answer (score 1):

After installing Ubuntu 14.04:

**Step 1**

Type the command below into terminal:
**`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:videolan/stable-daily`**

---

**Step 2**

**LibDVDCSS** is a library required for reading some DVDs. Unfortunately, due to legal issues, it is not included by default. This repository is provided by Videolan, and can be added with the code below:

```
echo 'deb http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list && echo 'deb-src http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list && wget -O - http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/videolan-apt.asc|sudo apt-key add -
```

---

**Step 3**

Next, check for updates with:
**`sudo apt-get update`**

Next, upgrade packages:
**`sudo apt-get upgrade`**

---

**Step 4**

Reboot your System and try to play your DVD in VLC.

---

Source: [Things To Do After Installing Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr)

Answer (score 0):

First install vlc media player from Ubuntu Software Center. Search for vlc in the search area located at the top right corner of the Software Centre.

Then, type this command to install all the codecs to play media in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This codec also includes libdvdcss. Read here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Now, you will be able to play any media in Ubuntu.

Thank You!

Comment: I installed wine and it started working